# How to change size of bokeh figure

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have read most of the documentation on bokeh and many of the examples. All of them contain the default square window. The only example I have seen that is the slightly different is [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/plot_gallery/iris_splom.html) which has subplots and sets height and width in the creation of a Plot object.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you've already created the plot, then you can use the `bokeh.plotting.curplot()` function to return the "current" plot, and then set its `height` and `width` attributes.  If you are building up a `Plot` object using the lower-level interfaces (e.g. the examples in `bokeh/examples/glyph/`, then you can just set those attributes directly as well on the plot object or in the `Plot()` constructor.

Alternatively, if you are using any of the glyph generation functions in `bokeh.plotting`, you can pass the `plot_width` and `plot_height` keyword arguments, e.g.:

```
line(x,y, color="#0000FF", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset",
     name="line_example", plot_width=800, plot_height=300)
```

Comment: Just FYI, in bokeh 0.12 i believe you can set this as a keyword in bokeh.plotting.figure() as mentioned below. **However**, the correct keywords are 'width' and 'height', not 'plot_width' and 'plot_height'. Moreover, I believe the value must be an integer, not a float. Since my figure is embedded, and I was tinkering on the server, this took me a while to figure. I could not find this information in their documentation of 'figure()', only an example. Hope it helps. To clarify by way of example: exampleFig = bokeh.plotting.figure(width=200, height=200)

Comment: **module 'bokeh.plotting' has no attribute 'curplot'**
I cant find anything about curplot()
any help? thank you

Answer (score 14):

You can add the plot_width/plot_height commands to the figure command itself.  Notice you can also add the resize tool to the set of tools via resize in the tools keyword var, which can be helpful.

```
bokeh.plotting.figure(x_axis_type = "datetime",    
  tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,resize,previewsave",plot_width=1000, 
  name="myplot")
```

Comment: This raises `ValueError: unexpected tool name 'resize', similar tools are reset` on bokeh 1.0.1

Comment: Looks like the resize tool was deprecated then removed:  https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4944.    In the .11 series it is found in the default tools : https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.11.1/bokeh/plotting/figure.py Subsequently removed by 1 series

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to answer my own question, this was actually easy.

```
bokeh.plotting.curplot().plot_height=400
bokeh.plotting.curplot().plot_width=800
```

Comment: **module 'bokeh.plotting' has no attribute 'curplot'**
I cant find anything about curplot()
any help? thank you

Comment: curplot() has been deprecated for some time.  You can see more information here: http://continuum.io/blog/bokeh-0.7#api-deprecations 

The API is more explicit now. Basically you keep track of plots (which is much better) you want to act on: 

        p = figure(...); p.circle(...); p.plot_height=400; show(p)

Comment: is there a way to set the width to the width of a jupyter cell?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a figure with name `p` you can simply do the following.

```
p.plot_height=400
p.plot_width=800
```

(Bokeh version 2.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.4.2:

An argument named `figsize` is there to set the size of the plot.

e.g.

```
count_df.plot_bokeh(
    title="Replenishment Count",
    xlabel="Date",
    ylabel="Number of Replenishment",
    figsize=(1000, 800),
)
```

**NOTE:** Only applicable on `plot_bokeh` method in dataframes.